# If a Java method's return type is int, can the method return a value of type byte?

Tags: java, methods, return-value, return-type

I'm preparing myself for the Java SE 7 Programmer I exam ([1Z0-803](http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=5001&get_params=p_exam_id:1Z0-803)) by reading a book called [OCA Java SE 7 Programmer I Certification Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617291048). This book has a numerous amount of flaws in it despite the author having 12 years of experience with Java programming and despite a technical proofreader, presumably on a salary.

There is one thing though that makes me insecure. The author says on page 168 that this statement is true:

> If the return type of a method is `int`, the method can return a value
>   of type `byte`.

Well I argue differently and need your help. Take this piece of code for an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // This line won't compile ("possible loss of precision"):
    byte line1 = returnByte();

    // compiles:
    int line2 = returnByte();

    // compiles too, we "accept" the risk of precision loss:
    byte line3 = (byte) returnByte();
}

public static int returnByte()
{
    byte b = 1;
    return b;
}
```

Obviously, the compiler do not complain about a different return type int in the `returnByte()` method signature and what we actually do return at the end of the method implementation: a byte. The byte uses fewer bits (8) than the int (32) and will be cast to an int without the risk of a precision loss. But the returned value **is** and will **always be** an integer! Or am I wrong? What would you have answered on the exam?

I'm not totally sure what the actual return type is, since this statement in the book is said to be true. *Is the cast happening at the end of our method implementation or is the cast happening back in the main method just before assignment?*

In the real world, this question would not matter as long as one understand the implicit casting and the risk of losing precision. But since this is just one of those questions that might popup on the exam, I'd love to know the technically correct answer to the question.

### *Clarification!*

The majority of the answers seem to think that I want to know whether one can cast a `byte` to an `int` and what happens then. Well, that is not the question. I'm asking what the returned **type** is. In other words, is the author's quoted statement *right or wrong*? Does the cast to an int happen *before or after* the returnByte() method actually returns? If this was the real exam and you would have got the question, what would you have answered?

Please see line1 in my code snippet. If what the author say is right, that line would have compiled as the returned value would have been a byte. But it does not compile, the rules of type promotion says that we risk loosing precision if we try to squeeze an int into a byte. For me, that is a proof that the returned value is an integer.

Comment: You are maybe overthinking this - I think the author just meant that `return b;` compiles, even if `b` is a `byte`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

- The value of the `byte` expression will be promoted to `int` before it is returned.
- The actual return type is as declared in the method signature - `int`.

IMO, what the author of that book wrote is more or less correct.  He just left out explaining the bit about the byte-to-int promotion that happens in the `return` statement when you "return a byte".

> Is the cast happening at the end of our method implementation or is the cast happening back in the main method just before assignment?

The cast (promotion) happens in the `returnByte` method.

> In the real world, this question would not matter as long as one understand the implicit casting and the risk of losing precision.

There is no loss of precision in promoting a `byte` to an `int`.  If the types were different, there could be loss of precision, but (hypothetically) the loss of precision would be the same wherever the promotion is performed.

---

The section of the JLS that deals with this is JLS 14.17, which says that the `return` expression must *assignable* to the method's declared return type.  It doesn't explicitly state that the promotion is done in the method, but it is implied.  Furthermore, it is the only practical way to implement this.

If (hypothetically) the conversion was done in the *calling* method (e.g. `main`), then:

- The compiler would need to know what the `return` statement is doing.  This is not possible, given that Java classes can be compiled separately.
- The compiler would need to know which actual method is going to be called.  This is not possible if the method is overridden.
- If the method contained two (or more) `return` statements with expressions that have different types, then the compiler needs to know which `return` will be executed.  This is impossible.

---

> If this was the real exam and you would have got the question, what would you have answered?

I would have answered ... "it depends" ... and proceeded to the alternative viewpoints.

Technically speaking the method is returning an `int`, but the `return` statement can take any expression whose type can be converted to an `int`.

But if someone said to me that the method is returning a `byte`, I would understand what they meant.

---

> Also, as far as i know methods/function use stacks for storage.etc and inside those stacks they store the return addresses not what (type) they are returning to. So, again the ambiguity arises (at least for me). Please correct me if I am wrong.

Yes, technically a method doesn't return a type.  (Not even if it returns a `Type` object.  That is an object that *denotes* a type, not the type itself.)  But everyone and his dog would happily say "the returnByte methods returns type int".

So, if you are going to be pedantic, then yes it is ambiguous.  But the solution is to not be pedantic.

Comment: well written! However, you say that the author is right. Thus that the method returns a byte. Yet you say that the cast happen before the method returns. I can not understand that. For me, the returned value is an int - no less and no more. Compare my line3 in the code snippet. If the returned type was a byte, I wouldn't have to cast it.

Comment: @MartinAndersson That method would return a value between -128 and +127 which can easily fit into any `byte` or `int` type. That is `byte` is a subtype of `int`. It is specified in the jls

Comment: Oh and one more detail. You quote me saying that in "the real world this would not matter" and comment that there is no loss of precision in the promotion from a byte to int - as if the quote would be wrong? But, what you comment is kind of what I already said, or meant with the "real world" sentence. And if the assignment would be the other way around (int -> byte), the code wouldn't even compile without an explicit cast. So again, I think the "issue" of my question doesn't matter. The "error" would have been caught by the developer.

Comment: boxed__I, I recently made an edit to the question and wrote a clarification that my problem has never been the promotion between primitive numeric data types. I'm more into what type the method returns. But thank you anyway for your concern!

Comment: When you wrote "in the real world this would not" matter, I took you to mean that there was a loss of precision , but it didn't matter.  In fact, there is no loss of precision here *at all*.  A loss of precision is possible in some cases; e.g. if return type was `float` and the expression value was `long`, then loss of precision is possible.  However, that's not the criterion that matters.  If you read JLS 14.17, the actual criterion that the compiler checks is that the expression is *assignable* to the method's declared return type.

Comment: @StephenC :`The cast (promotion) happens in the returnByte method.` statement is incorrect then?

Comment: @StephenC :Doesn't this widening happen at the `main` (in this case)?

Comment: boxed__I, I agree with you. Where the promotion happens is what makes the statement right or wrong. If it is as Stephen puts it, which I believe is true, then the statement is wrong.

Comment: @MartinAndersson - it is up to you what you think the quoted statement is saying and therefore, whether it is "wrong".  (The issue of whether the author is "wrong" or not doesn't interest me much.)

Comment: @boxed__l : I have explained in my Answer.  1) That's what the JLS says, and 2) doing the widening in the caller is not possible in general for the 3 reasons I identified.

Comment: @StephenC : for 3.) IMO is false, cause as you said `[...]The type T must be assignable (§5.2) to the declared result type of the method, or a compile-time error occurs.` hence all return statements should agree with the _method return type-contract_ (don't know if its the technical term) (ex. if return type is int return can be byte,int,short & char)

Comment: @StephenC :Also, as far as i know methods/function use stacks for storage.etc and inside those stacks they store the return addresses not _what_ (type) they are returning to. So, again the ambiguity arises (atleast for me). Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain it's the same as doing `myInt << 24`, getting the last eight bits, therefor an imminent loss of precision if the integer is over the value of 255(2^8).

Comment: I didn't know a `<<` operator existed? And a `byte` can only hold values -128 to +127. A quick tip to calculate the value range for any signed data type (that is all but the `char`) in Java is the following: Calculate `(2^bits) / 2`. That will give you the lowest value if you can imagine a negative sign in front of the calculated sum. Then subtract one from the sum, that will give you the highest positive value the data type can hold.

Comment: I don't see how this answer solves the problem. There won't be any loss of precision as both are signed and you are converting from `byte`(smaller) to `int`(larger).

Comment: Yes! I know =) Please see the newly added clarification in my question.

Comment: @MartinAndersson comment was for user2507230 not you :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes the statement is valid. A `byte` will always fit into an `int` comfortably.

```
byte => int //no precision loss
int  => byte //precision loss
```

But if you are doing:

```
byte => int => byte //you won't lose any data
```

Which is what you are doing. Does that help?